# How to fix application-window resizing error for a BrowserView in electronjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

so I'm writing on a electron application at the moment.
To make my application a bit smoother I created a `BrowserWindow` and loaded just the menubar and the background.

After that I added a `BrowserView` to show the acutal content.

Code for my `BrowserWindow`:

```js
function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        frame: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    })

    win.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views/index.pug'));

    win.on('closed', () => {
        win = null;
    })

    win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        win.show();
    })
}
```

Code for my `BrowserView`:

```js
function createViews() {
    contentView = new BrowserView({ webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true } });

    win.addBrowserView(contentView);

    contentView.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 23, width: win.getBounds().width, height: win.getBounds().height - 23 });
    contentView.setAutoResize({ width: true, height: true });

    contentView.webContents.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views/imageGallery.pug'));
}
```

*(If there is a spoiler function to hide the code: I'm sorry, I didn't find any)*

Once I create the window it works like intended, also the normal resize via mouse-drag works perfectly.

> Now my problem is, as soon as I maximize or unmaximize my window with the functions `win.maximize()` and `win.unmaximize()` my `BrowserView` gets resized. But the resize doesn't fit the `BrowserWindow` anymore. The content of the `BrowserView` is being cutted on the right side.

Window after being maximized:
[image: Maximized Window]

Window after being unmaximized:
[image: Unmaximized Window]

Comment: I have the same issue... Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
    function createWindow() {
      // Create the browser window.
      const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ useContentSize: true });
      const view = new BrowserView();
      mainWindow.setBrowserView(view);
      view.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 600 });
      view.setAutoResize({ width: true, height: true });
      view.webContents.loadURL("https://youtube.com");
    }
```